# making views for quiz type of application

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I am working on a project, in this project after login user has to answer 199 question.

there is for kind of questions like true/false, single selection, multiple selection, and short answer

so can you guys tell me what approach i should use to make views, becoz client strictly saying that each question will show on single screen.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes I have create this type of Application.You just use the One Custom Cell and make design of your view and return your array in Tableview cell. so it is better to use custom cell. Otherwise you use PageView Controller to display Question.Even I have also use this and it works fine.